# Cursor moves to next line when leaving insert mode with remapped <C-Space>

Tags: vim

I have remapped `<C-Space>` to `<Esc>` using the this line in my .vimrc:

```
inoremap <C-Space> <Esc>
```

when running under MacVim or gVim (I use `inoremap <Nul> <Esc>` when I don't have gui_running)

It works fine except when I leave insert mode with the cursor at the end of the line.  That is, if I do `A` to put the cursor at the end of the line, and then type `<C-Space>`, the cursor moves down to the first column of the next line.  Hitting `<Esc>` leaves the cursor on the last character.

Why does it do this, and how can I stop it? The `<Nul>` remapping doesn't have this problem.

Comment: Do you have a trailing space in your mapping?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly the problem. You should post it as an answer, and I'll mark it as correct. Strangely, I never knew what space did before in normal mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely you have a trailing space in your mapping. Removing it should solve your problem. Space move the cursor one character forward.